# Lambda and map, param by reference - compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I've tried to narrow down my problem to a minimal example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::map<std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::vector<int>>> other;

    if (true)
    {
        std::for_each(other.begin(), other.end(),
            [&](std::pair<std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::vector<int>>> & data)
            {
                result.insert(result.end(), data.second.second.begin(), data.second.second.end());
            });
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error C2664: 'void main::<lambda_1b93236899a42921c1aec8d5288e5b90>::operator ()(std::pair<std::string,std::pair<unsigned int,std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>>> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'std::pair<std::string,std::pair<unsigned int,std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>>> &'
```

As far as I can tell the lambda parameter is indeed a reference to the type that is contained by the map which we are iterating through. That is the type I am supposed to be using, right?

If I remove the amperstand before `data` it compiles.

Why?

I do not want to pass each element by value, as those collections will contain a lot of data in my real program.

If I replace the lambda param with `auto &` it compiles, which leads me to believe the type in the lambda param does not match the type contained by the map, but it sure looks like it does to me. Also, why would the original compile without & if the type is wrong?

What am I missing/not understanding?

Comment: I typedef all this stuff out in the original code, I wanted to be explicit in the example here in order to spot any potential problem I am not aware of.

Comment: You are missing `const` on the key type. Use `[&](decltype(other)::value_type&)` or `[&](auto&)`.

Comment: @Oktalist Took me several hours to figure out today :-P

Comment: It works without `&` because `pair<T,U>` is implicitly convertible to `pair<V,W>` if `T` and `U` are implicitly convertible to `V` and `W`.

Comment: It isn't related to the lambda. Try a plain function and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::map<Key, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)'s `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, not `std::pair<Key, T>`. The version without an ampersand makes a copy of each pair. Since you can copy `const Key` to `Key` everything is fine. Add a `const` to your lambda's parameter type.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::map<std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::vector<int>>> other;

    if (true)
    {
        std::for_each(other.begin(), other.end(),
            [&](std::pair<const std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::vector<int>>> & data)
        // Add this const ^^^^^
        {
            result.insert(result.end(), data.second.second.begin(), data.second.second.end());
        });
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been strugglig with the very same problem today.

I solved that making the key value type in the `std::pair` `const`:

```
[&](std::pair<const std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::vector<int>>> & data)
           // ^^^^^
```

After thinking about that a bit, it's quite logical:
You cannot change the `key_value` of a `std::map`'s entry to something different. So if it's working with an `auto` loop and a reference it needs to be specified as `const`.